# Cannot correctly print integers that are returned from a function in C++

Tags: c++, methods

I am trying to program something for a class that involves creating an object using a `Token` class and printing it out. Here is my main method:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    Token tok(10, "test", 1, 2);

    printf("%d\n", tok.type());
}
```

This is my `Token.cc` file with relevant methods:

```
Token::Token(int t, string str, int l, int c) {
    int tokType = t;

    string lexStr = str;

    int lineNum = l;

    int charPos = c;
}

int Token::type() {
    return tokType;
}
```

And this is my `Token.h` file:

```
#ifndef TOKEN_H
#define TOKEN_H

using namespace std;
#include <string>

class Token{
private:

public:

    Token(int t, string str, int l, int c);
    ~Token();

    int type();

    int tokType;
    string lexStr;
    int lineNum;
    int charPos;
};

#endif
```

Program compiles fine, however when I run it prints a seemingly random number such as `1475212264` or `-258154088` or some other random number of that length.

Any ideas what could be going wrong? This is driving me crazy.

Thanks

Comment: So I do not need to re-define `lexStr` in the .cc file?

Comment: [mcve] as usual please. Your question lacks essential information/debugging efforts.

Comment: or so: http://ideone.com/1PrZZm

Answer (score 1):

I believe that in your constructor, because you are redefining all of your variables, you are limiting their scope to the constructor. What this amounts too is that the member variables of the Token class end up not being set to the values you passed to the constructor. So you end up with uninitialized data as a result of type().

Just try removing the datatypes in the constructor like so:

```
Token::Token(int t, string str, int l, int c) {
    tokType = t;

    lexStr = str;

    lineNum = l;

    charPos = c;
}
```

And see if that helps.

Comment: The right way to so it would be to *initialize* the data members in the constructor's initialization list.

Comment: @juanchopanza is right. knkp, you are that little step away from having an answer that is both correct and good. Right now it is correct.

Comment: It's a good answer. It will fix the problem. Not the best coding style, but then again the author is already using printf so perhaps that's a lesson for another day.